# How to view foreign language(i.e. Bangla) characters in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, character-encoding

Here's my code inside a .ctp file in CakePHP:

```
<div class="AccordionPanel">
        <div class="AccordionPanelTab">জন্ম নিবন্ধন</div>
        <div class="AccordionPanelContent">
            <?php echo $html->link(__('থানা', true), '/ReportBirthRegistrationStations/'); ?>
            <?php echo $html->link(__('অফিসার', true), '/ReportBirthRegistrationOfficers/'); ?>
         </div>
</div>
```

So it's pretty clear what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to write Bangla characters inside my view code in my CakePHP project, and I want to display them in my view page.

When I try to load the view page - weird, unreadable characters appear instead of Bangla characters.

I included this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

the UTF-8 encoding at the top of the file, but still it didn't work.

I included the UTF-8 encoding in view layout files as well, but still facing the problem.

How can I view Bangla or any other foreign characters in CakePHP? IS there any support in CakePHP for Bangla?

My IDE is Netbeans 8.0.1.

My CakePHP version is 1.2.5, and PHP version is 5.2 [due to working in a very old project that is being maintained since 2008-09]

**Edit - 1:**

I've tried adding the following -

```
-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

in my `netbeans.conf` file in etc folder of my Netbeans installation folder. By doing that, I wanted to make sure that my file is saved in UTF-8 encoding. But my problem is still not solved.

**Edit - 2:**

Forgot to mention one important point. Whatever I'm trying to display, has nothing to do with my database values. These are just labels, I just want to view these labels in Bangla on page load.

Comment: Make sure that you have removed the `Html->charset()` call in case you are using the default layout, and check that `App.encoding` in your `core.php` is set to `UTF-8`, that your server responds with `UTF-8` in the `Content-Type` header, that your files are actually UTF-8 encoded, and that the font in use can display your chars. ps, there is no CakePHP 1.7

Comment: @ndm Please check my corrected post.

Comment: Is the output like ????  ?

Comment: @AlimonKarim It's some thing like this - à¦¸à§à¦

Comment: <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('অফিসার'), array('action' => 'add')); ?></li>
it's working fine for me. 

I think it's not problem of cakephp.If you use avro please write in notepad++ after select encoding-> encode in utf-8.

Comment: @AlimonKarim What browser are you using? And what is your Cake version?

Comment: I am using Mozilla and version 2:0. Please try 1st by this process if you failed I will try it in your cake version.

Comment: @AlimonKarim Vai, still having problems. Is my version responsible for this? 1.2.5 doesn't support Bangla fonts?

Comment: Have you tried using english texts in your view and putting the Bangla in the *.po file?
I was in my application successful with Thai. At least it looked like correct Thai as far as I can judge, but the letters looked fine and not like you described above.
So I guess the problem is not Cake but somewhere in the chain you are missing an utf-8 setting.

Comment: @CalamityJane No i haven't tried it yet. Can this be done in Cake 1.2.5?

Comment: Sure in every version of Cake :)

Comment: Brother I don't think it's  a problem of cakephp version.Contact me brother it may I help you.
skype : alimon karim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem was in my `default.ctp` file in `app/views/layouts` folder.

The `<meta http-equiv>` tag there was not UTF-8 encoded, it was ISO-8859-1 encoded. Like the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

This is Cake standard - the `default.ctp` view file in the `app/views/layouts` folder is shared throughout the entire application and it defines the default behavior and shared attributes of all view pages.

Since this is a very old project and the HTML version back then was HTML 4, the code was written this way. UTF-8 encoding is supported by HTML5. Check the following for more details: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp

I just had to change this to UTF-8 encoded and then it worked.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The problem had nothing to do with Cake version, nor with PHP version. Rather, it was all about the HTML version and corresponding code that created the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Add this code to your ~/app/config/core.php file:

```
Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

And in your page  section add:

```
 <?php echo $html->charset(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your web server does probably not set the correct content type for the request.

You could try to set it manually in your AppController in the beforeRender();

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Also note that when you write something to the out stream in the controller before the headers are sent to the client, that also the encoding will be broken. (Happens often in debug mode)